# Jquery POST with same request not work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

i have next problem

```
$("#btnsave").click(function () {
    $.post('svld.php', {
        'fnd': $('#fnd').attr("value")
    }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }, 'json');
}
```

slvd.php

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

    var_dump(json_encode($_POST));
```

in request i see next

```
fnd http://ya.ru
```

and have great response

```
string(24) "{"fnd":"http:\/\/ya.ru"}"
```

but alert(data) not runed

if i do same request on file parse.php in same folder

```
if($_POST['fnd']){

 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($cntTags->returnArrayTags());
}
```

all work perfect 
Have idea what it can be ?

header list

```
Date Thu, 08 Jul 2010 12:16:02 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0
X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.0
Content-Length 38
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=99
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Type application/json
Host localhost
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Language ru,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive 115
Connection keep-alive
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost/tz/
Content-Length 22
Cookie spylog_test=1
```

Comment: What do you mean with *alert(data) not run* ? Does it show nothing in the alert or isn't it even executed?

Comment: What is "Заголовки запросапоказать исходный код" and what is it doing in the headers? And the callback will not be run if the request failed or the response format is not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your HTTP request is returning this string:

```
string(24) "{"fnd":"http:\/\/ya.ru"}"
```

What happens is that jQuery is trying to parse that but it fails because it's not a valid JSON string.

Try using `echo` instead of `var_dump`:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

`var_dump()` outputs other information that you don't need, and that will screw up jQuery's JSON parsing.

Comment: echo json_encode($_POST);

it was solve proble 

thanks I spent 2:00 h on this )
thanks Luca Matteis again !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Content-Type application/json Заголовки запросапоказать исходный код
```

looks alien to me. Looks like a character-set failure.

try

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: But in char set i have utf-8 and message only eng ? or you mean else ?

Comment: when i try charset but did not produce results but it was all smooth thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem like a valid content-type regardless of the charset. It should just be `application/json` or `text/x-json` (not sure of the difference).